# How to use TextView Search to load more in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a `recyclerview` using data from an API that uses a `TextView` to filter out the list and search for my item. Everything works perfect. My problem is my `Recyclerview` is too big, so I set it to only run through the first 10 items, then on a `TextChange` it would load more. I basically copied my method, named it `loadmoredata()` and it ran the exact same code just now it was set to `array.length`. It worked to but my issue is that on each text or backspace the method I assume keeps running, and the items keep adding adding so I start to two, then three, then four of the same item.

How can I fix this? Is there an easier way also to just keep my one method, and on text change have that method expand? I tried to do this by in my `adapter` changing the `getcount()` to return 50 but once I use the `searchtext` my app crashes and I do not know how to change `getcount()` from 50 to `listitems.length()` when the text is changed. My code is posted below:

***Recyclerview Code***

```
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    loadRecyclerViewData();

    SearchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            filter(editable.toString());
            loadmoredata();
        }
    });

    return v;
}



private void filter(String text) {
    List<ListItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ListItem item : listItems) {
        if (item.getHead().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()) || item.getDesc().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
            filteredList.add(item);
        }
    }
    adapter = new MyAdapter(filteredList, getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


private void loadRecyclerViewData() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);


                        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            ListItem item = new ListItem(
                                    o.getString("name"),

                            );

                            listItems.add(item);
                        }
                        adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, getContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `loadmoredata()` is the same as `loadRecyclerViewData()`, you are always putting the same `10` first itens on the list, because of this line of code: `for(int i=0; i<10; i++)`.

`loadmoredata()` needs to start where it last left off, from the first time it needs to start at `10` to `20`, then from `20` to `30` and goes on, the code should be something like this

```
int last = 0;

private void loadmoredata() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                        for(int i=last; i<last + 10; i++){
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            ListItem item = new ListItem(
                                    o.getString("name"),
                            );

                            listItems.add(item);
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        last += 10;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Now you can call `loadmoredata()` every time and it will only get new itens, be carefull with the end of the pagination, if `last + 10` is bigger than `array.lenght` it needs to stop.